# JQuery Mobile afterPageLoaded Event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM and I need to run an event after the page is loading

I've been googling for many hours and found this url:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/2151#issuecomment-1709291

Anyone know anything about "afterPageLoaded" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `pageload`.

Example:

```
$( document ).bind( "pageload", function( event, data ){

 // do stuff after page loaded

});
```

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

The link you sent shows that the lead developer closed that issues 7 months ago. If you have a specific questiona bout that v3n3's request or github, you should follow up there.